# Can we call a sub-flow or private flow dynamically without using a choice router?

Tags: mule, mule-component

Suppose I have a main flow and there are several sub-flows. I need to call a particular sub-flow if I have the right parameter without using choice component.
Basically, I want to ask if sub-flows can be parametrized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Here's an example:

```
<flow name="testFlow1" doc:name="testFlow1">
        <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
        </poll>

        <set-variable variableName="flowName" value="testFlow2"
            doc:name="Variable" />
        <flow-ref name="#[flowVars.flowName]" />
    </flow>

    <sub-flow name="testFlow2" doc:name="testFlow2">
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="sub" />
    </sub-flow>
```